# Please help SQL in Visual Studio c#

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had 2 tables which  tblProduct and tblStock

**tblProduct**

```
ProdName    Price
P8          234
S7          234
M8          234
MD8oz       234
TO8         306
TO8JP       354
LR8         354
GBB8        354
GTF8        354
SS8         354
MD12        340
P750        322
S750        322
MD750       322
P300        132
S300        132
M300        132
MD NEON300  132
1.25L       228
CANS 250ML  348
CANS 330ML  552
TO355       585
LR330X12    210
G350        576
G500        760
SSE300X24   444
SSE300X12   222
PW350       254
PW500       230
PW1L        220
```

**tblstock**

```
ProdName    Quantity   INdate                    PriceperQty      TranStatus
M300         2         2018-11-07 23:46:05.800   132              IN
M300         2         2018-11-08 11:23:34.227   132              OUT
P300         23        2018-11-08 16:52:01.260   132              IN
MD12         12        2018-11-08 16:52:10.147   340              IN
TO8JP        3         2018-11-08 16:52:18.843   354              IN
SSE300X24    13        2018-11-08 16:52:28.587   444              IN
P8           43        2018-11-08 16:52:37.237   234              IN
1.25L        21        2018-11-08 16:52:43.843   228              IN
P8           32        2018-11-08 16:52:50.050   234              IN
S7           43        2018-11-08 16:52:54.900   234              IN
S7           32        2018-11-08 16:53:07.460   234              IN
P8           23        2018-11-08 16:53:19.020   234              IN
```

I want to produce the results like below from these two tables.

[image]

Comment: What have to tried so far, can you post your attempt SQL please? What were the errors you got, or what was wrong with the results? Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, it's for asking question for specific coding problems. You need to show us your code first for us to be able to help you fix it.

Comment: @Larnu im using this query 
select min(a.ProdName), max(b.Quantity),max(b.Size),min(b.Reference)
from tblProd a
INNER JOIN tblStock b ON a.ID = b.ProdID

Comment: @Larnu also thi query but I can't show the load 1,2,3
select min(a.ProdName), max(b.Quantity)
from tblProd a
INNER JOIN tblStock b ON a.ID = b.ProdID
where b.TranStatus = 'IN' and  b.Reference = '0'
group by a.ProdName,b.Credat

Comment: I'd guess you could use ROW NUMBER OVER PARTITION to put tblstock into order and get a load number for each row, then PIVOT to turn that into the table you want. But I'm not an expert here. Or you've put C# in the title: are you asking how to do this in LINQ not SQL?

Comment: Put the (formatted) SQL in your question please, not in the comments, @mr.jm

Comment: @Larnu sorry im often to ask question to this site thats why i don't know how to edit.

Comment: There's a button 'edit' just above the comments. Or here's the link: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53204927/edit)

Comment: @Rup I'll search more about row number over partition.i put c# visual studio because i use the built in sql in vs 2017 and using c#.

Comment: There is no problem statement here (except for "please help"), and so it is not likely to help future readers. I would very much like to see improvements as well.  I think it is appropriate to vote this as off-topic for now, but if it can be edited appropriately, it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function make row number for `tblstock` table.
then use condition aggregate function to make pivot.

```
SELECT ProdName,
       [1st load],
       [2st load],
       [3st load],
       [4st load],
       price,
       (([1st load]+[2st load] +[3st load]+[4st load]) * price) 'Total'
FROM (
    SELECT  t1.ProdName, 
            MAX(CASE WHEN t2.rn = 1 then t2.Quantity ELSE 0 END) '1st load', 
            MAX(CASE WHEN t2.rn = 2 then t2.Quantity ELSE 0 END) '2st load',
            MAX(CASE WHEN t2.rn = 3 then t2.Quantity ELSE 0 END) '3st load',
            MAX(CASE WHEN t2.rn = 4 then t2.Quantity ELSE 0 END) '4st load',
            t1.Price
    FROM tblProduct t1 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ProdName order by INdate desc) rn
        FROM tblstock
    ) t2 on t1.ProdName = t2.ProdName  
    GROUP BY  t1.ProdName,t1.Price
)t1
```

Comment: It work a bit..my move now to modify my query..thank you very much for the idea!

Comment: Sir, I already edited the tables question... how about if i add column in tblStock which indicate the out of item to 1 column..Please see sample in question. Thanks

Comment: You probably just have to ignore the out rows in the left join for the partition and then either add a simpler equivalent left join that returns out rows only and then show rn = 1 from that table in the out column, or if there can only ever be one then a simpler left join that just matches any out row. Hopefully you can see how to do this yourself!

Comment: @rup Thanks for the feedback..i understand now the sql query.. i can now modify it..